# I am getting auth token is not valid from LinkedIn login

Tags: linkedin-api

I have tried to get data from linkedin I got an access token and when trying to access data with auth token I am getting `Empty oauth2 access token` error.

I got the token with this url:  https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login

I have given respective params:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth_token=81--7a2e3182-577c-4acd-ba14-12bbcbe84948&oauth_verifier=28551

When I hit this URL directly to server I am getting this kind of response instead of getting data.

```
{"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}
```

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use oauth2_access_token name for the token param

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to that answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?**oauth2_access_token**=81--7a2e3182-577c-4acd-ba14-12bbcbe84948&oauth_verifier=28551

instead of

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?**oauth_token**=81--7a2e3182-577c-4acd-ba14-12bbcbe84948&oauth_verifier=28551

Answer (score 0):

You can get access token from https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth?clientId= ENTER YOUR CLIENT_ID.